# How to transfer searched data from database to another table with complete data rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql

I'm doing a small project,a POS one. There are two tables; the purpose of the first table is to fetch the products from search box with two column names from the database.If the products are available, I will click it and transfer it to the second table.I'd watch tutorials how to transfer table row data from another table but my problem is I have only two columns from the first table whereas in the tutorial its identical to the second table.
Can someone give me a hint where to start? Or is it possible?

[image]

This is my js code:

```
    <script>
    function tab1_to_tab2()
    {
        var table1 = document.getElementById("table1"),
            table2 = document.getElementById("table2"),
            checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("tab1");
            console.log("Val1 = " + checkboxes.length);
            for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)
                if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
                    var newRow = table2.insertRow(table2.length),
                        cell1 = newRow.insertCell(1),
                        cell2 = newRow.insertCell(2),
                        cell3 = newRow.insertCell(3);

                        cell1.innerHTML = table1.rows[i+1].cells[1].innerHTML;
                        cell2.innerHTML = table1.rows[i+1].cells[2].innerHTML;
                        cell3.innerHTML = table1.rows[i+1].cells[3].innerHTML;

                        i--;
                        console.log(checkboxes.length);
                }
    }
</script>
```

But I got an error in the console:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertCell' on 'HTMLTableRowElement': The value provided (1) is outside the range [-1, 0].

As I google some tutorials,I think checkbox would be better instead of clicking the rows.
Can someone help me about this?

Comment: Why are you transferring to second table, why not just selecting two column from the table and pass the result to the UI?

Comment: First table is for searching products and if the product is the right one to be buy by a customer, I will click it and transfer to the main table with all the Description,Price,Qty and unit.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO newTable (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM oldTable

Comment: if you have an identical name in a table which you want to  INSERT you can use  SELECT column1 as newName FROM oldTable

Comment: What I mean is my UI. Not the back end.

Answer (score 0):

I'd got the answer now.

---

Using this code

```
<script>
    function tab1_to_tab2()
    {
        var table1 = document.getElementById("table1"),
            table2 = document.getElementById("table2"),
            checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("tab1");
            var qty = 1;
            console.log("Val1 = " + checkboxes.length);
            for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)
                if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
                    var newRow = table2.insertRow(table2.length),
                        cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0),
                        cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1),
                        cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2),
                        cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);

                        cell1.innerHTML = table1.rows[i+1].cells[0].innerHTML;
                        cell2.innerHTML = table1.rows[i+1].cells[1].innerHTML;
                        cell3.innerHTML = table1.rows[i+1].cells[2].innerHTML;
                        cell4.innerHTML = table1.rows[i+1].cells[3].innerHTML;
                        console.log(checkboxes.length);
                }
    }
</script>
```

[image]

The 'QTY' and 'Subtotal' columns is still lacking but I think its better than nothing. I'm still open who will help me out about this problem. :)